# C Programming: Sum of Prime Numbers of a Given Range Printing Both The Prime Numbers and The Sum

Tags: c

I was creating code that prints the sum of a set of prime numbers of a given integer. Here is what I have created so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int is_prime(int m)
{
    int i;
    for(i=2; i<=m/2; i++)
    {
        if (m % i==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    int num, min, max, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &min);
    scanf("%d", &max);
    for(num = min; num <= max; num++)
    {
        if(is_prime(num))
        {
            sum += num;
            printf("%d", num);
        }

    }
    printf("=%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
 }
```

If I entered 10 as the minimum, and 20 as the maximum it would print out 11, 13, 17, 19, and it would print out the sum of 60. I was simply wondering how to print '+' between the numbers that are listed when it is executed.

Comment: For a start you do not need to consider even numbers

Comment: Forget your primes. Your question is "how do I print '+' between the numbers in a list?"

Comment: save data in array and + sign at end

Comment: This question can be answered by a simple Google search. As @nima_moradi pointed out, the question is "how to format strings in C". This topic has even a Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to print no plus sign in front of the first number, and to print a plus sign in front of all other numbers. To achieve this I am using a boolean with false/true values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int is_prime(int m)
{
    int i;
    for(i=2; i<=m/2; i++)
    {
        if (m % i==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    int num, min, max, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &min);
    scanf("%d", &max);
    bool first = true;
    for(num = min; num <= max; num++)
    {
        if(is_prime(num))
        {
            sum += num;
            if(!first) 
            {
                printf("+");
            }
            printf("%d", num);
            first = false;
        }

    }
    printf("=%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
 }
```

This code also works with using an integer instead of a boolean: `int first = 1;` and `first = 0;`

Comment: +1, but I wonder, given that OP is making `is_prime` return an int of 0 or 1, if the code they are using is so old as to have no `bool`... While your code looks fine, you may want to change it to match the style of the posted code, or at least call out the distinction.